# How to retrieve data from two objects in json file?

Tags: angularjs, json

If I have records for users and also records for orders, it is proper to save them like that:

```
{
    "users": [
        {"id": "1", "name": "Allan", "age": "40"},
        {"id": "2", "name": "Jack", "age": "50"}
    ],
    "orders": [
        { "id": "1", "item": "item 1", "userId": "1"},
        { "id": "2", "item": "item 3", "userId": "1"},
        { "id": "1", "item": "item 4", "userId": "1"},
        { "id": "1", "item": "item 51", "userId": "1"},
        { "id": "2", "item": "item 4", "userId": "1"}   
    ]
}
```

as you can see I'm coming from the SQL world so I'm saving the 'orders' data with foreign key, is that the right way to save this data as json and if so how can I get all the users with there orders?

Thanks!

Comment: put your view and controller code

Comment: Just left join them on the server.

Comment: i am not getting your question **how can I get all the users with there orders?**

Comment: My first question is if this is the right way to save this data in a json format or maybe I should have everything together (denormalization)?

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL or Mongodb ???

Comment: JSON is a very flexible construct which enables you to arrange the data in a variety of ways, all of them consistent. The main question is: How do you plan to **digest** the JSON into your database? As for the way you show, this is as suitable as it would be to have, for each user, an array of the orders. Again, no true answer can be given without knowing what you have at hand to push the info into your DB.

Comment: By the way, your data appears to be quite suitable for TABLES, not for DOCUMENTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your json object is in the above mentioned structure you can use this code to filter the orders

```
    var oJson = {
   "users": [
         {"id": "1", "name": "Allan", "age": "40"},
         {"id": "2", "name": "Jack", "age": "50"}
   ],
   "orders": [
         { "id": "1", "item": "item 1", "userId": "1"},
         { "id": "2", "item": "item 3", "userId": "1"},
         { "id": "1", "item": "item 4", "userId": "1"},
         { "id": "1", "i`enter code here`tem": "item 51", "userId": "1"},
         { "id": "2", "item": "item 4", "userId": "1"}   
]}
   for(var i=0; i<oJson.users.length;i++){   
      for(var j=0; j<oJson.orders.length;j++){
         if (oJson.users[i].id == oJson.orders[j].userId) {
            console.log( oJson.orders[j].item, oJson.orders[j].userId)
            //your logic here
         } 
      }
   }
```

But it is better to use sql joints to merge the orders and return the objects like this

```
 {
"users": [
    {"id": "1", "name": "Allan", "age": "40","orders": [{ "id": "1", "item": "item 1", "userId": "1"},{ "id": "2","item": "item 3", "userId": "1"},{ "id": "1", "item": "item 4", "userId": "1"},{ "id": "1", "item": "item 51", "userId": "1"},{ "id": "2", "item": "item 4", "userId": "1"}   
]},
    {"id": "2", "name": "Jack", "age": "50","orders":[]}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the objects for json file into two varible

var a=value.users;

var b=value.orders;

value is nothing but the whole json file

then you can match them against each other like

a[0].id==b.[0].id